# Is there a way to have Parent and child Nodes in Neo4J?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I would like to introduce hierarchy in my database.

For example:

School Node: "Cambridge" offers,

- Course Node: "Maths"
- Course Node: "English"

---

School Node: "Harvard" offers,

- Course Node: "Maths"
- Course Node: "English"

---

So when a student enrols in "Maths", it's Harvard->Maths instead of Cambridge->Maths

Is there a way to do this? Or do I need to design my nodes with more unique properties?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In you use case, would it be possible to give courses a unique identifier? Because, that will probably help both on read and writes to the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

I assume you're having trouble using MERGE to create the nodes in the structure you want.

You would run into this problem if you tried to MERGE the nodes individually, like so:

```
MERGE (s:School {name:'Harvard'})
MERGE (c:Course {name:'Maths'})
MERGE (s)-[:OFFERS]->(c)
```

The problem with that query is that the MERGE will find any Maths course and use that node (or those nodes, if there are many) so the same Maths course would be used in both hierarchies, which isn't what you want.

Instead of doing the MERGE of the :Course node alone, MERGE it with a relationship to the school:

```
MERGE (s:School {name:'Harvard'})
MERGE (s)-[:OFFERS]->(c:Course {name:'Maths'})
```

The second MERGE will use the bound `s` node for Harvard. It looks for the path first, and if it finds that a Maths course is already offered by Harvard, it will use that. If it doesn't find this path, it will create it, by creating a new :OFFERS relationship to a new 'Maths' :Course node.

More info on using MERGE in these cases here:

https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-how-merge-works/